# How do I check whether the virtual address belongs to User data space or User code space?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

mm_struct is mapped to bss, code, data segments. Should I be checking against their start and end ranges. How do I determine whether the given virtual address falls in USER data or USER code space?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I sadly don't know the answer, but as a reference, in Windows programming it was available both in a global and a syscall.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to check precisely: do you just wish to check if some virtual address is mapped as data (RW) vs code (RX)? Or do you want to check if the address corresponds exactly to the `.text` or `.data` sections of the task which owns the `mm_struct`? In the first case that should be easy, in the second case it does not make much sense really since once the binary is loaded it's hard to tell which `vm_area_struct` corresponds to which section.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli The problem statement is -  one for page faults in the user's code segment, one for page faults in the user's data segment, and one for page faults that are not in either the code segment or the data segment. (Most of these will be in the stack.) and the hint is - The memory management structure keeps track of the start and end of the code and data segments. So, I am assuming that it is the second case, using mm_struct, it needs to be in 1 of the regions

Comment: Let me make an example: assume the program does `mmap(0x123000, 0x1000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);`, what would you define an address in such page as? Code, data or other? What about the same but without `PROT_EXEC`?